# same locations memory but the result false (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

i just get confuse about the identity operator in python , how to use it and how the identity operator works , i'll give you the example :

```
var_1 = 10
print (id(var_1) is id(var_1))
```

the result is "False" , i don't know why be like that , some one can explain in simple way ? and explain the id() function works .

thank's

Comment: You want to compare the *objects* with `is`, but their identification number with `==` equals. So try `id(var_1) == id(var_2)`. The *only* guaranty of the `id` function is that it returns a number that uniquely identifies your object (for it's lifespan).

Comment: sorry what do you mean the identification number with == ?

Comment: I mean use `==` operator to compare the id's

Answer (score 0):

your use of `id()` is redundant, the `is` operator takes the two objects and compares their addresses , when you do `id(var_1)`  you're creating a nameless variable that has the value of the `id` of `var_1` then you create another nameless variable, it will have the same value but it won't be the same `id` you can check this by printing `id(id(var_1)` and seeing it's different every time:

```
var_1 = 10
print id(id(var_1))
#18438008
print id(id(var_1))
#18438032
print id(id(var_1))
#18438056
```

if you want to see if an object is the same you need to either do `id(var_1) == id(var_2)` or as recommended: `var_1 is var_2`

Comment: so the `is` just only compare 2 diferrent variable , and if i try to compare same variabel i only get the 'False' for the result , Because if i do  `print (id(var_1) is id(var_1))` i creating the diferrent a nameless variable ?

Comment: @NANGAPARBATSUMARNO `is` compares *objects*. Variables are just references to objects. the `id` function will return new `int` objects that are not *the same object* but  are still *equal*. So, consider `[] is []` vs `[] == []`

Comment: @NANGAPARBATSUMARNO you got it